# can not access apache2 server global virtualhost from local

Tags: http, apache2

I can access my appache2 server with `example.com` from global host(like 4G network etc.),
but not access from local host.
How can I fix it?

Appache2 configuration like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example
        ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you add your domain with your IP localhost to this `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` yet?

Comment: Oh! I'm stupid. Access from windows, and only change wsl host config. Thank you!

Comment: It's okay mate, I just help you as much as I can help :)